# Is there a way to fake "slow" storage for testing?

Tags: windows, storage

I need to test my system with varying degrees of storage latency.

Is there a software solution (for Windows) that would allow me to "fake slow" storage for testing purposes?  I'm basically looking for something where I could have a new drive letter backed by real storage with a configurable "minimum latency setting".

Does such software exist off-the-shelf, or can it be achieved through some other means?

Comment: Minimum latency would be a terrible way to fake slow storage. With random, multi-user/multi-process workloads, it's not the baseline (zero queue depth) latency that limits capacity; rather, it's IOPS. Delaying each request by 10ms isn't enough.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to get an older usb stick to test on?

Comment: Yes, an old usb stick to test on would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your software in a virtual machine, using Windows Server 2012R2 as a hypervisor, you can set storage QOS on each disk, limiting the throughput to the IOPS you want.

Comment: @MichaelJSwart This is probably the best solution for testing purposes (I believe similar results can be achieved with VMWare). You can determine the IOPS load for normal operation, then set the limit at varying levels lower than that threshold in order to simulate "overload" and see how your application behaves.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with any products that will do this for SATA or SAS. For that you'll need to introduce a real load and performance test.

If you are referring to network storage there are a number of options.

I generally whip up a set of VMs, one of which is set up a transparent network bridge. I prefer CentOS but that's just my background.

By using the [TC / EM packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth) you can emulate a slow network, therefore slow NAS, iSCSI SAN or SMB response. I've done so on several occasions.

Comment: I know on FreeBSD you could hack something together using [GEOM](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/geom-class/), but that would be pretty painful (and won't work for your Windows case here). [Trondh's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/545219/32986) or the network-based ideas suggested here seem to be the closest to what you want (simulating slow/overloaded storage).